# How do I insert a default value as part of a SQL Server View definition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a number of different views which use the same underlying table, but each uses a different default value for the FK.

So for my attempted code:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwTest]
 AS
SELECT     
Id, 
C1 AS |TestCol, 
COALESCE(GroupId,3) AS GroupId 
FROM         dbo.tblTest
WHERE     (GroupId = 3)
```

I know "3" is hardcoded, but will be replaced.

This is the line I believe is causing the hassle:

```
COALESCE(GroupId,3) AS GroupId
```

I need "3" to be inserted into tblTest.GroupId each time I insert a record into vwTest.

Thanks.

Comment: you can look at [instead of insert triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this. Having had a look at this I am a little confused as to what the "Alter View" script should look like. Would really appreciate an example using the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create an instead of trigger on the view**

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37d19b/1/0)

**sample tables / view**

```
create table tblTest( id int identity, c1 varchar(10), groupid int );

create view vwtest as select c1, COALESCE(GroupId,3) GroupId 
from tblTest
where GroupID = 3;
```

**create a trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on vwTest
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tblTest (c1, GroupID)
       SELECT c1, 3
       FROM inserted
END;
```

**put some test data into table  / view**

```
insert into tblTest( c1, groupid ) select 'row 1' ,3 ;
insert into tblTest( c1, groupid ) select 'row 2' ,1 ;
insert into vwTest(c1) select 'row 3';
```

**see what we get**

```
select * from tblTest;
select * from vwTest;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very comprehensive reply. Really appreciated.

Comment: Also like the SQL fiddle utlity. Learn something everyday !!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do that is to define an instead-of trigger on each view.